Firebase Authen/Author integration for ASP.NET Core 6
I am trying to integrate Firebase authentication with ASP.NET Core. I can interact with Firebase, however, face issue when authenticate the API.
Error description on JWT event:
OnAuthenticationFailed: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '3'. 
Number of keys in Configuration: '0'. 
Exceptions caught:
 '[PII of type 'System.Text.StringBuilder' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
token: '[PII of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. See https://aka.ms/IDX10503 for details.

What I have done: I mostly follow instructions on Youtube, work with them, not with me.
Nuget package:
<PackageReference Include="FirebaseAdmin" Version="3.0.0" />

My configuration:

Trying to call the securetoken URL:

My JWT config:
public static IServiceCollection FireBaseJWT(this IServiceCollection services, WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

    // Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Config/firebase.json")),
            });

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["FirebaseJwt:Firebase:ValidIssuer"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["FirebaseJwt:Firebase:ValidIssuer"],
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["FirebaseJwt:Firebase:ValidAudience"],
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                    };

                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });

    return services;
}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});

builder.Services.FireBaseJWT(builder);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.MySwaggerConfig();
builder.Services.MyDIConfig();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

What I have been considering:

Normally, there should be IssuerSigningKey in TokenValidationParameters which is our private key, I wonder if it has anything to do with firebase authentication key in this image:


This document say we need to manually verify the token, there also a video build a middleware for authentication handler. Does this worth it when it come to authorization handler since we need to deal with claims stuffs.



The error message you're getting is because the JWT token does not contain kid, which is necessary for the signature validation process. you could double check the appsetting configuration. in your JWT configuration add code to get the public key and use in validation. add this code IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; to get more detail about the issue.
